# In LXML how can I keep the tags, but remove all the inline styling etc?

Tags: python, html, lxml, lxml.html

I know I can remove tags like `<h1>` etc with LXML but how can I get it to keep the tag but remove everything else like so:

```
<h1 style='font-size: 24px; margin: 0px 0px 12px; font-weight: 600;&#13;
      line-height: 28px; color: rgb(23, 43, 77); font-family:&#13;
      -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto,&#13;
      "Noto Sans", Ubuntu, "Droid Sans",&#13;
      "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; font-style: normal;&#13;
      font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal;&#13;
      letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start;&#13;
      text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal;&#13;
      widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;&#13;
      background-color: rgb(244, 245, 247); text-decoration-style:&#13;
      initial; text-decoration-color: initial;'>This text must stay</h1>&#13;
```

The above should be once cleaned:

`<h1>This text must stay</h1>`

Currently I'm doing this, but I can't quite get it to keep the tag and remove the tag class etc:

```
safe_attrs = list(lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs) + ['bgcolor']
        lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs = safe_attrs
        lxml.html.clean.Cleaner.safe_attrs = lxml.html.clean.defs.safe_attrs
        cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner(style=False, remove_tags=['body', 'pre'], safe_attrs_only=True,
                                          safe_attrs=safe_attrs, kill_tags=['title', 'code'])
        return cleaner.clean_html(data)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the tag class etc"? There is no class in your sample.

Comment: You're right, I didn't include that sample.  Some of the non included data has class info in it but I suspect the idea is clear.  I want the tag, without any of the stuff like classes, styles, etc inside them.

Comment: Well, the idea would be clearer if the sample was more representative. It is not obvious what the problem is.

Comment: That's fair, more examples would be good.  I believe the part of the question that shows an example h1 with all the data and then shows what it needs to look like after `<h1>This text must stay</h1>` pretty much says what's required.